# cordova window.pageYOffset always return 0

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

It is possible to get `window.pageYOffset` at cordova?
Are there alternatives `$(window).scrollTop`?

Can I scroll to a concrete position in pixels using cordova?

For example like `$(window).scrollTop(100)`?

Comment: I'm also facing this problem.

Answer (score 1):

After spending so many hours found the solution for this. You can use `$(document).scrollTop()`. But this applies to all the pages in the app. So you can make it happen to the specific page you want as shown below.

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");
    if(activePage[0].id == "pageID");{
        var ypos = $(this).scrollTop();
        alert(ypos);        
    }   
});
```

You can scroll to a concrete position using the same way.

Hope this helps.